# Java Generics Class as method parameter

Tags: java, android, generics

I have a TabListener in Android defined in this way:

```
public static class TabListener<T extends Fragment> 
    implements ActionBar.TabListener { ... }
```

An I have this source code:

```
Tab myTab = myActionBar.
                newTab().
                setText("Home").
                setTabListener(new TabListener<MyFragment>(
                    this, 
                    "Home", 
                    MyFragment.class
                ));
...
```

Now I want to put this into a method:

```
addTab("Home", ???);

private void addTab(String text, ???) {
    Tab myTab = myActionBar.
                newTab().
                setText(text).
                setTabListener(new TabListener<???>(
                    this, 
                    text, 
                    ???.class
                ));
    ...
}
```

What I have to fill in instead of `???`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your tab listener needs the type parameter to be a subclass of `Fragment`

```
public static class TabListener<T extends Fragment>
```

Therefore, you need to make sure it is the case in your code

```
addTab("Home", ???);

private <T extends Fragment> void addTab(String text, Class<T> clazz) {
    Tab myTab = myActionBar.
                newTab().
                setText(text).
                setTabListener(new TabListener<T>(
                    this, 
                    text, 
                    clazz
                ));
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
addTab("Home", MyFragment.class);

private void addTab(String text, Class<? extends Fragment> clazz) {
    Tab myTab = myActionBar.
            newTab().
            setText(text).
            setTabListener(new TabListener<>(
                this, 
                text, 
                clazz
            ));
    ...
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I use JRE6: ``'<>' operator is not allowed for source level below 1.7``

Comment: that can be solved by introducing a factory method. but it's fine to have a  `<T>` to `addTab()`

Answer (score 2):

Something like this is probably what you're looking for:

```
private <T> void addTab(String text, Class<T> clazz) {
    Tab myTab = myActionBar.
            newTab().
            setText(text).
            setTabListener(new TabListener<T>(
                this, 
                text, 
                clazz
            ));
    ...
}
```

Comment: wildcard is better. and the class should be a subclass of Fragment

Comment: I get this error here ``new TabListener<T>``: ``Bound mismatch: The type T is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <T extends Fragment> of the type MyActivity.TabListener<T>``

Comment: This way, it works: ``private <T extends Fragment> void addTab(String text, Class<T> clazz)``